# How to avoid purrr::pmap_dfr converting Date to numeric

Tags: r, purrr

Why is purrr::pmap_dfr converting Date to numeric and how do I avoid it?

Here is an example with a data.frame with three different types of columns.
As you can see there is a Date column. After using purr::pmap_dfr it is numeric:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df <- data.frame(
  a = c('a', 'b', 'c'),
  b = c(10, 20, 30),
  c = c(100.5, 200.5, 300.5),
  d = c(ymd("2016-01-01"), ymd("2017-01-01"), ymd("2018-01-01")),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

f <- function(a, b, c, d){
  r <- data_frame(a=a, b=b, c=c, d=d, class.of.d=class(d))
  return(r)
}

pmap_dfr(df, f)
```

The result is

```
 # A tibble: 3 x 5
      a     b     c     d class.of.d
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>      <chr>
1     a    10 100.5 16801    numeric
2     b    20 200.5 17167    numeric
3     c    30 300.5 17532    numeric
```

Comment: Looks like it is a [bug](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/issues/251).   Multiple issues were filed.  Check [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/issues/358)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a known issue with pmap_dfr. See https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/issues/358

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are using pmap_dfr here. What are you trying to map?

```
f <- function(x){
  r <- data_frame(a=x$a, b=x$b, c=x$c, d=x$d, class.of.d=class(d))
  return(r)
}


f(df)
```

yields

```
 a         b     c d          class.of.d
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <date>     <chr>     
1 a      10.0   100 2016-01-01 Date      
2 b      20.0   200 2017-01-01 Date      
3 c      30.0   300 2018-01-01 Date
```

Maybe you mean

```
h <- function(x){
 class(x)

}

map_dfr(df, h)
```

which returns

```
  a         b       c       d    
  <chr>     <chr>   <chr>   <chr>
1 character numeric numeric Date
```

The way `map_dfr()` works is that it applies the function (in this case class()) to each column in the data frame.  You don't write out the columns in the function, just take the data frame and map does the work of splitting it up.

Comment: That's an example. My real problem is much complexer so I stripped it down to this example here.

Comment: Well it's really not clear what you are asking or why you would use map in this way. Are you trying to turn each column into a separate data frame?